# Confusion about direction of friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, string

A motor is dragging a log up a slope with a cable. When the cable breaks, what happens to the forces? There is no more tension, but does the direction of friction change since the log is now moving downwards? Why else would the speed be decreasing?

Comment: What do you mean "...the speed be decreasing"?

Comment: shouldnt the resultant force and motion be in different directions for the speed to be decreasing

Comment: Are you talking about before or after the cable breaks

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that friction acts in a way to oppose relative motion of object

[image]

### 1st case

Since the log is moving up relative to incline  friction acts downward working as an opposition

### 2nd case

Now there is only a component of mg which causes log to move downwards relative to incline so friction changes its direction by same logic.

The speed is decreasing because the force whi h caused it to move up is no more there and mg developed is in a direction opposite to velocity attained so retardation  occurs and object eventually stops

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the dynamic friction for is always opposing the direction of motion. If it would not to that, the friction force would accelerate your object, which does not make sense.

Comment: It's not direction of motion rather relative motion :]

Comment: Every motion is relative motion.

Comment: In case of rotational motion it might be possible that friction opposes relative motion but at the same time supports motion think about it

Comment: Here is an example where the relative motion is important. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598523/friction-causing-acceleration

Comment: I don't think this is very relevant in the context of the level of this question.

Comment: Bernhard describes 2 things in opposition to each other, so it is clear in his answer that they are relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

**If the log is moving** after the cable breaks, the direction of static friction will be opposite to its velocity, so it will change direction.

But it is also possible that the log stays still after the cable breaks. In that case you will determine the direction of friction by saying that it should compensate the other forces. This direction will most certainly change in this case also. Note that the magnitude of this friction should remain below a certain value $\mathbf{T} \le \mu \mathbf{N}$, otherwise the log starts sliding.

There are other factors that could make the speed decrease, but it mostly depends on what you include in your model.